# Simple query to a WSS/MOSS list from remote client

Tags: web-services, moss, wss

What is the simplest way to query a WSS/MOSS list from a remote client

Using /_vti_bin/lists.asmx and XML fragments for the query seems to be a large chunk of work for a simple task?

I have found the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/karine/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28) which helps a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution -  Linq for Sharepoint how cool is that!

http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoSharePoint

It's not finished, but what it has is fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you write in .NET, reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Dll, get an instance of SPWeb and through that an instance of your list. Then you can access it directly, or create a CAML query through defining an SPQuery q, setting the CAML query string to q.Query and getting the SPListItemCollection col = list["myList"].GetItems(q);

Comment: Sorry, from a remote client, not on the server